# What's difference between sp_addrolemember and alter user with default schema...?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Was wanting to add full access for a developer to a database. 
I wanted them to be able to have full control over it...including deleting it if they wanted.
Somehow I stumbled upon two ways.  Are these the right ways??

1. What's the difference of between access/permissions between the both commands?
2. What is the correct command to accomplish what I want?
   Thanks.

Command 1

```
USE [testdb1]
GO
ALTER USER [john] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO
```

Command 2

```
USE [testdb1]
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'john'
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/ms187750.aspx) is a great source for [answering](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176060.aspx) that:

> sp_addrolemember
>
> Adds a database user, database role, Windows login, or Windows group
>   to a database role in the current database.
>
> ALTER USER
>
> Renames a database user or changes its default schema.

Note also the syntax:

```
sp_addrolemember [ @rolename = ] 'role',
    [ @membername = ] 'security_account'


  -- SQL Server Syntax
ALTER USER userName  
     WITH <set_item> [ ,...n ]
[;]

<set_item> ::= 
      NAME = newUserName 
    | DEFAULT_SCHEMA = { schemaName | NULL }
    | LOGIN = loginName
    | PASSWORD = 'password' [ OLD_PASSWORD = 'oldpassword' ]
    | DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = { NONE | <lcid> | <language name> | <language alias> }
    | ALLOW_ENCRYPTED_VALUE_MODIFICATIONS = [ ON | OFF ]
```

In other words, using `sp_addrolemember`, you could only **add** `database user, database role, Windows login, or Windows group` in the **current database**.

But using `ALTER USER`, you could alter its name, its default schema, its login name, its password, etc... which certain is unable to be done by using `sp_addrolemember`.

Check the two MSDN links. They are great source for info using `SQL Server`

As for your case, you probably want to use `sp_addrolemember`, provided that you already have a role which could give the user the access that they need (most probably `db_owner`).

```
USE [testdb1]
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'john'
GO
```

When you alter default schema of a user, it does not mean that they get new role - but they get new default schema, and the accessibility will depend on the security rules in the new schema for the existing user role. It *could* give you what you want, depends on the security rules for the user in the default schema it has.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [latest sp_addrolemember documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addrolemember-transact-sql), `sp_addrolemember` should be avoided and [ALTER ROLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-role-transact-sql) should be used instead.

> This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature. Use ALTER ROLE instead.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between the two as of SQL Server 2012.

```
alter role [RoleName] add member [MemberName];
```

is equivalent to

```
exec sp_addrolemember N'RoleName', N'MemberName';
```

References:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189775.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187750.aspx